# plone4.2.5 ubuntu12.10 64bit "ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found."

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.10, hashlib

I am trying to install Plone 4.2.5 on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit machine. But getting:

> "ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.", with "./install.sh  standalone"

## Error Log

```
$ ./install.sh standalone
Stand-Alone Zope Instance selected

Detailed installation log being written to /home/criticalboot/Downloads/Plone-4.2.5-UnifiedInstaller/install.log

Rootless install method chosen. Will install for use by system user criticalboot

Installing Plone 4.2.5 at /home/criticalboot/Plone

Python found at /home/criticalboot/Plone/Python-2.7/bin/python; Skipping Python install.
Found existing buildout cache at /home/criticalboot/Plone/buildout-cache; skipping step.
Generating random password ...

ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/criticalboot/Plone/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/criticalboot/Plone/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/criticalboot/Plone/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/criticalboot/Plone/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/criticalboot/Plone/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/criticalboot/Plone/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/criticalboot/Plone/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/criticalboot/Plone/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
```

Comment: This is a Python installation problem, nothing to do with Plone itself.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Python is also installed by Plone through Unified installer. So How to install SSL functions that are missing

Comment: Install the OpenSSL development packages; `libssl-dev` *I think*.

Comment: Its my bad :(.  In hurry I missed out [debian-libraries page](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/installing-plone/installing-on-linux-unix-bsd/debian-libraries). After doing this every thing went cool.